# calculating volume of a horizontal cylindrical tank from depth

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Has anyone found a good formula to convert a depth of fluid to a volume remaining in a tank for a cylindrical tank laying horizontal? (with or without half sphere end caps)
Much Thanks!

Comment: Is this a mathematical or Mathematica-related question? If it is generally about math, this question should be migrated...

Comment: The version without half sphere end caps was asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3750/752).

Comment: (Pi*r^2)/2 + Sqrt[h]*(h - r)*Sqrt[-h + 2*r] + 
 r^2*ArcTan[(h - r)/(Sqrt[h]*Sqrt[-h + 2*r])]

Comment: Not a duplicate: This tank has half-sphere end caps.

Answer (score 0):

You could see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_segment) on the area of a circular segment and multiply by the length.  If you want spherical end caps, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) on a spherical cap.  The two ends together make a sphere.